# web3js questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

I always a bit in doubt when I see questions with `web3js` code. I start each question from analyzing version of `web3js`. There are lots of differences between 0.x and 1.x. It takes time to check it. I think a person who asked a question should be in charge to provide version of `web3js`

Would it be better to introduce tags for it?

For instance `web3js-v0.x` and `web3js-v1.x`

Answer (score 4):

Given that other StackExchange sites with similar version issues do exactly this - have tags for each version - I would say yes.

Create the version tags you describe.  Leave the existing [web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js) and change its wiki to state that it for version-agnostic questions only.

Ideally existing questions would be retagged with the version tag. However, given that there are over 2000 such questions, this wouldn't be worthwhile.  Questions should only be retagged in this way if they are being edited for other reasons.

Comment: In the (extended) wiki for `web3js` it might be good to add something like "it should be for version-agnostic questions only, but many past questions will mean `web3js-v0.x`"

Comment: All these tag wiki changes have now been made.